# Access Filter By Field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Just curious if filtering fields is a possibility in Access? Or if there is VBA code that allows the "Show" Box in the query to be checked or unchecked based on an if statement?

Basically I have about 80 fields in my database and I want to create a table with only 3 of them, based on a value in a combo box. 2 are always the same, and the 3rd would be based on a combo box.

Can I do that?

Comment: You can "filter fields" by altering the columns that are selected in a query. I'll have to make a lot of assumptions about your code, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by altering the SQL of the query object you want to modify. So if your query object is named "qryMyQ", and your combo box object is named "cboDropDown", then the VBA would be the combo box's AfterUpdate event and would look like this:

```
Private Sub cboDropDown_AfterUpdate()
    Dim qryDef As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String

    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMyQ")

    sql = "SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [" & cboDropDown.Value & _ 
          "] FROM yourTableName " & _
          " WHERE [" & cboDropDown.Value & "] = ""applicable"""

    Debug.Print sql 'This line will allow you to troubleshoot the SQL that is to be executed.'
    qryDef.sql = sql

    Set qryDef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Just a note here; but you'd want to make sure that users cannot add or edit the combo box options to avoid sql injections. Not sure how friendly your userbase is.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Additional question, the records in the third column either say "applicable" or are null. Is there a way to add criteria so it only pulls the "applicable" records?

Comment: yes, you can add a where clause in the sql statement. If that is always the condition you want, you can just hard code it in. I'll update the answer to show this...

Comment: @cm2115 - actually, first - a question. Are you saying the the third column will always have "applicable" records in it, no matter which choice the user picks from the drop down?

Comment: Yes, so the first 2 columns have various other information, and the rest to follow have records filled with either applicable or null

Comment: I'm getting a missing operator error when the code runs. The values in the combo box match the field titles it's searching through... any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to see what text is in the `sql` variable right before the `qryDef.sql = sql` line executes?

Comment: sql = "SELECT Milestone/Task/Deliverable, " & Combo0.Value & _
              " FROM A4_Only " & _
              " WHERE " & Combo0.Value & " = ""Applicable"""

        qryDef.sql = sql

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you meant.... but it's the qryDef.sql = sql that errors out

Comment: @cm2115 I actually want to see what is the string value inside the `sql` variable when you try to execute `qryDef.sql = sql`. So to see that, you can set a breakpoint on the line of code that is breaking and run it up to that point, and then in the Immediate Window type `?sql`, press `Enter`,  and it will print out the value inside `sql`. I want to see what SQL it is trying to run.

Comment: "object doesn't support this property or method"  when the code runs with print sql

Comment: @cm2115 - okay, lets take a step back. I've edited by answer to include bracketed column names (just to make sure no column names are responsible for breaking the sql statement) and I've added a Debug.Print line that will reveal the value inside the `sql` variable. If you continue to get errors, please post the sql statement that gets written to the immediate window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183135/discussion-between-archerbird-and-cm2115).